# Send data to server on browser close

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement fully transparent autosave system for logged users, but got stuck with sending data to server on browser close. I can bind some functionallity to unload event, but I was unable to send any data to server (using jQuery/Ajax).

Is it possible to send data to server, when user closes browser?

**P.S.** Given, that even GMail doesn't automatically saves draft, but alerts about possible data loss, thinking that task is quite complicated...

Comment: you can save document automatically when user type. like in google docs.

Answer (score 2):

Set your AJAX call to synchronous. the async call will let the browser move on before the op completes.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ async : false })
```

please note cross domain and jsonp calls do not support synchronous calls [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).unload( function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: yourUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: "value1=value",
        cache: true,
        success: function(response){

        }
        });
    } );
```

you also pass multiple data in data params like "value1=value&value2=value" and {yourUrl} is relative or absolute url

Comment: Do you know that this will work even as the browser is closing?

Comment: Seems you have to forget about onunload event, if you'd like to create trully cross-browser appliction, because of Opera. Sad((